# Trying to write a function in JS passing through true and false statement

Tags: javascript, function

I have a little question. I want to write a function in javascript and the function needs to take two extra parameters, for when the function is true and false. But I don't know how to write it. So, I want something like this:

```
function greater (para1, para2, casetrue, casefalse) {
    if (para1 > para2) {
       casetrue
    }
    else {
         casefalse
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Because I wrote that function and than I called the function with 
`greater(5,3, function() { return "is greater" }, function() { return "is smaller" })` and it didn't work.

Can anybody please help? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way, otherwise you'll be returning a function:

```
function greater (para1,para2,casetrue,casefalse) {
  if (para1 > para2) {
    return casetrue();
  } else {
    return casefalse();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's ok. Everybody been there. You also can `greater(5,3, function() {return "is greater"},function() {return "is smaller"})()`

Comment: @nnnnnn in is original version he is returning functions instead of strings. That is why it doesn't work in the first place. I'll put it in a separate answer to avoid misunderstandings. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I realised that after commenting, so I deleted my comment. At first I thought you meant that you could do the extra `()` with your version of the function...

Comment: @nnnnnn, it was confusing. Another answer works better. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function greater (para1, para2, casetrue, casefalse) {
 if (para1 > para2) {
   return casetrue();
  }
  else {
   return casefalse();
  }
}
```

Comment: The `casefalse` and `casetrue` arguments are intended to be callback functions, one of which will be executed within `greater()`. But if they _were_ supposed to be booleans why on earth wouldn't you just use `true` and `false` rather than `new Boolean(0)` and `new Boolean(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

To make the function *greater* return "is greater" or "is smaller" one must return the return value of the parameter functions:

```
function greater(para1, para2, casetrue, casefalse) {
            return (para1 > para2) ? casetrue() : casefalse();
}
```

Tested on Firefox 24.0 / Linux

Answer (score 0):

Like has been suggested in other answers, the `greater` function is returning functions instead of strings. If this is the desired behavior, you can call the returned function with an extra pair of brackets:

```
greater(5,3, function() {return "is greater"},function() {return "is smaller"})()
```